# Using dynamic DB name in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Create view xxx
as
Select * from
DBName.dbo.table1
```

I have an above mentioned view where `DBName` is dynamic. How can I create this view? I know we can't use dynamic variables in a view. I wanted to know how it can be done with the help of a function.

Comment: It must be a view?

Comment: Yes. It must be a view.I was thinking of calling the output of select * from in a view through a table valued function. In function we can use dynamic variables if i am right

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use dynamic sql in a function, more reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607935/call-dynamic-sql-from-function).

Comment: lets create view in every potential database. There is something wrong in basic idea of view

Comment: Why not create the view in database with name `DBName`, and select from it like `SELECT*FROM DBName.dbo.xxx;`?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use synonyms here just pass a DbName as variable like this

```
Declare @Dbname varchar(255)
Declare @qry varchar(255)

Set @Dbname="Name of the dataBase"

Set @qry='Create synonym ABC for'+@DbName+'.dbo.table1'
Exec (@qry)
```

Now use this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from sysobjects where id=object_id(''SN_DWTableCustomer'') and xtype=''SN'')
BEGIN 
DROP VIEW xxx 
Create view xxx as Select * from ABC 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
Create view xxx as Select * from ABC
END
```

For better understanding use the below links
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/synonyms.php
[What is the use of SYNONYM in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246006/what-is-the-use-of-synonym-in-sql-server-2008)

Please reply.

Comment: But what if DBName changes. I again have to create the view by running above mentioned code.Is there any other solution?

Comment: Simply drop the view and again recreate it or you want view in another table.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DBname varchar(max) = 'newdb'
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'create view MyView as select * from '+@DBname+'.dbo.test'

EXEC (@sql)

SELECT * FROM MyView
```

Comment: But what if DBName changes. I again have to create the view by running above mentioned code.Is there any other solution?

Comment: Then you can create Stored procedure with above first 3 lines with the parameter @DBName and execute the sp. Please give more details if this solution not suits your requirement

Comment: I cant use SP. I was thinking of calling the output of select * from in a view through a table valued function. In function we can use dynamic variables if i am right

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(100) 
SET @DB = 'Your_DBName' DECLARE @CreateViewStatement  NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @CreateViewStatement = '      USE '+ QUOTENAME(@DB) +';      
EXEC(''
         CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyTable] AS
         SELECT * FROM Your_Table
  '') '
EXEC (@CreateViewStatement)
```